# Wierd noise on GND when I touch a metallic object to it

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, pcb, electromagnetism, esd

I am facing a problem.

I have a PCB designed which fails ESD tests.

The PCB is powered by an external power supply that provides 12V  to the system (from 240V AC.) The power supply is CE certified and passed all the EMC tests so it isn't the issue.

The PCB has an MCU which has push buttons hooked upto it. The push buttons are pulled up and work as active LOW. The MCU detects any falling edges via interrupts and then does the input processing.

The issue is that when there is an air ESD discharge (via ESD gun) near the device, the buttons get triggered.  There is an LCD display which also resets.

The same thing happens when I use a mosquito racket and discharge it via a screwdriver.

[image]

Here is an image of what I captured on the buttons pin via as oscilloscope:

[image]

You can see, the button is pulled to 3v3 and when there is a discharge all hell breaks loose.

The funny thing is when I probe the 3v3 and GND lines of the device and touch any GND with a mettalic object (screwdriver or a rod) a similar event occurs.

[image]

This is just by touching any mettalic object to the PCB gorund.

The 3v3 rail just drops to 0 for some ns and then rises up.

I think this is the exact thing that is happening with the ESD discharge as well.
I tried the same experiment with a ST discovery board and it gave the same results.

[image]

As I touch the screwdriver to the SDCARD connector(which is grounded) the 3v3 line drops.

What i have tried so far:

1. Placed a RC network at the input of each input button pin.
2. Placed TVS diodes at the input of each pin
3. Placed an external 10k pullup on each pin in junction with the internal pullup.
4. Tried to create a sheilding mesh via conductive copper tape aroung the PCB

Still the same thing happens.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

How do I fix it?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing. It is not only about the PCB but the whole system. By system, I mean what external connections the PCB has, how it is even powered?

Comment: @Justme The PCB is powered by an external power supply that provides 12v to the system(from 240v AC). The power supply is CE certified and passed all the EMC tests so i believe it isn't the issue.

Comment: The external power supply only provides 12v and GND to the device, there is no earth as the device sits in a plastic enclosure.

Comment: OK, but blindly believing something is not the same as verifying it because it could be the problem. And you don't mention if the power supply plug has earth terminal and if it does is it connected to earthed wall socket. Does the problem go away if a 12V battery is used?

Comment: No, the system also has a Texas Instruments BMIC inside, which provides power via a 12v battery in case the AC power supply is disconnected, and we have the same issue with the battery as we have when the power is given via the external power supply. (ESD test failing).

Comment: OK, so now there is a battery after all. If you don't describe the system fully, there is no way to know what the issue is. What does the board do and what connections it has?

Comment: Well, the system is a product for my company so I dont want to disclose details but I would help being as generic as possible, The board has only 1 input that is the DC plug for the power supply. If that is unplugged, the system is isolated, being in a plastic enclosure. Only contact for the user to the device is a membrane keyboard.

Comment: Also based on the picture of Discovery board, you have long wires to oscilloscope which will give false measurements of fast transients due to wire inductance.You may see things on the scope that are not actually there.

Comment: this is the main reason that using external interrupts for pushbuttons is a bad idea. Ok if you use the interrupts to wake the device but you still need code to debounce the inputs. You should filter all inputs be it analog or digital in the code. Determine what values are valid inputs - if a pushbutton input is only microseconds wide, then clearly that is not a valid press. Just because a power supply has passed EMC tests and has CE doesn't exclude it from suspicion. By design it may contribute to the problem.

Comment: Is that a Conductive mat vs an anti static mat that the board is sitting on?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the ESD discharge, you need to find out what frequencies the racket produces that interfere with your circuit. They most probably are low frequencies (for example up to ~300Mhz). To find this out use either a spectrum analyzer of the FFT function of your oscilloscope. You might face the same issues if you use a cheap room fan, turn it on and plug/unplug it on the AC mains fast and continuous. Cheap room fans are a classic device/case that interferes with surrounding electronics. Lower frequencies are easier to penetrate through metal and other objects, so they most likely causing you the issue.

After you find out the frequencies that cause problems to your device, you might start shielding the device using ferrite beads for the frequencies that produce interference, ferrite clamp-on your cables for the same frequencies, shielded cables, using a chassis metal box, filtered AC main's input (if your device gets plugged into the AC mains), and finally use (and search for) [PCB EMI design techniques](https://www.protoexpress.com/blog/7-pcb-design-tips-solve-emi-emc-issues/)  that reduce these issues significantly, like using capacitors on every cable that comes on the PCB, use as short traces as possible and make the trace's width as small as possible (the smallest width that can carry the current you need).

Regarding the touching of a metallic object on anything that is GND on your circuit, yes it might as well cause you issues since it acts like an antenna and will capture radio waves and move them on your GND plane. GND/common plane on a pcb is not something that one can use for shielding or touching to other metal objects. GND and GND plane is used as reference voltage and should not be "touched" or messed with. I recommend you watch [How to Achieve Proper Grounding - Rick Hartley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuUZEjARPY). He explains that GND is not 0V everywhere and is not used to shield the PCB. Also [Eric Bogatin makes a great speech](https://youtu.be/y4REmZlE7Jg?t=2413) about -among other things- copper pour on PCB, it might be a source of your issues.

EDIT:

You commented

> The power supply is CE certified and passed all the EMC tests so i
> believe it isn't the issue.

If your PCB is not designed for EMI suppression, (or is too sensitive to EMI), the power supply will not be able to help you. You might still need Ferrite beads clamp on the power cable, AC filtering input etc.

Finally, since you are looking for high(er) frequencies, make sure your are probing your circuits using proper high frequency techniques:

[image: correct probing]
[Image source](https://www.electronicspecifier.com/products/power/oscilloscope-probing-techniques-for-measuring-power-supply-ripple)

And not like that:

[image: Mistake probing]
[Image source](https://www.electronicspecifier.com/products/power/oscilloscope-probing-techniques-for-measuring-power-supply-ripple)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, although I dont feel that you have quite answered the question. I dont think the mettalic object capture so much RF energy from the environment to bring the whole 3v3 rail down? Can it be because earth ground and the device ground are not at the same potential so when i do touch it with a rod, energy is capacitively couopled from device ground to earth ground?

Comment: Τhat is a possibility yes! Still, nothing conductive should touch the GND. SD card's metallic enclosure should not be tied to GND. It should be floating so it will be used as shielding. (GND should not be used as shielding). I could not comment all of the above (comments are limited characters), so I thought I would post it as a reply, as I have had similar issues in every project I make, all the time. Low frequency signals mess up my PCB.

Comment: It is unclear why GND should not be used as shielding and then what should be used as shielding? Usually leaving things floating just makes things worse.

Comment: @Justme Well I think this depends on the needs of a project and the environment it will operate at. Based on the video I posted in this answer " How to Achieve Proper Grounding", Since GND is something you need to be "clean" and close to 0V, one should not use it as shielding, since this will mess the GND signal, it wont be 0V anymore and issues will occur. He also says that "laptops dont have shielings (most of them have plastic enclosures). Phones dont needs shielings".

Comment: I don't intend to watch a 2 hour video to address any claims. However, if the power supply is ungrounded and has an Y capacitor between mains side and low voltage side, or the oscilloscope is connected to ungrounded outlet, there would surely  be charged capacitances in the circuit that can cause surges when they charge another thing when they touch.